# VB.NET: Change Background Opacity

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET form with a red background and white text. I want to change the opacity of the background (not the text) to 50%; how would I go about accomplishing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Form.Opacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx) property.

Snippet from MSDN link:

```
Dim instance As Form
Dim value As Double

value = instance.Opacity

instance.Opacity = value
```